# Cloudera Host Installation failure: Failed to detect Cloudera Manager Server

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-manager

I'm trying to put a host on a hadoop cluster using the Cloudera Manager.

The two computers I am using for this are the following:

```
10.10.10.9 is supposed to be a DataNode and my first host 

10.10.10.10 has the Cloudera Manager and will be the NameNode
```

The manager is having trouble with the "Cluster Installation" part of the "Add Hosts to the Cluster" scenario on the GUI.

I get the following error when the manager tries to detect the Cloudera Manager Server:

```
BEGIN host -t PTR 10.10.10.10 
10.10.10.10.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer stardestroyer.riis.local. 
END (0) 
using stardestroyer.riis.local as scm server hostname 
BEGIN which python 
/usr/bin/python 
END (0) 
BEGIN python -c 'import socket; import sys; s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET); s.settimeout(5.0); s.connect((sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]))); s.close();' stardestroyer.riis.local 7182 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "<string>", line 1, in <module> 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth 
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args) 
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known 
END (1) 
could not contact scm server at stardestroyer.riis.local:7182, giving up 
waiting for rollback request
```

I tried to do as Cheloute instructs in the following link, but it didn't seem to fix my issue. I also had a different error than the poster.
[Cloudera Manager. Failed to detect Cloudera Manager Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912384/cloudera-manager-failed-to-detect-cloudera-manager-server)

If the following is used on the commandline, there's no error.

python -c 'import socket; import sys; s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET); s.settimeout(5.0); s.connect((sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]))); s.close();' **10.10.10.10** 7182

I'm not really sure how to fix this in the Cloudera Manager, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I could have my system administrator delete my reverse DNS entry and the manager ended up working. I don't know if there is a better solution (there likely is), but this is the one I came up with.